# reset progress bar to its initial condition with jquery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Is there a way to reset progress bar like this:

```
<progress></progress>
```

To its initial state when element uploaded & progress bar is full

(in initial state chrome shows progress bar with line going back & forth)

doing something like this just clears it:

```
$('#progress-'+id).attr({value:0})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `value` attribute altogether:

```
$('#progress-'+id).removeAttr('value')
```